# Prism Forms INavigationAware OnNavigatingTo not updating ObservableCollection

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Prism which helps me in binding my view to the view model. Using INavigationAware, I am hoping to update the Observable collection in my Listview from OnNavigatingTo(). On debugging this method is accessible, however it does not seem to update the ObservableCollection that is bound to the view.

Below is the ViewModel, that is inherited from Prism's BindableBase and INavigationAware:

```
public class QuoteDetailPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{

    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Message> _messages;
    private ObservableCollection<Message> Messages
    {
        get { return _messages; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _messages, value); }
    }

    private Author _selectedAuthor;
    private Author SelectedAuthor
    {
        get { return _selectedAuthor; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedAuthor, value); }
    }


    public QuoteDetailPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        Title = "Text Messages";
    }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        var id = -1;

        if (parameters != null && parameters.ContainsKey("id"))
        {
            int.TryParse(parameters["id"].ToString(), out id);
        }

        if (id > 0)
        {
            Title = "Contact Message";
        }

        var msgs = new List<Message>()
        {
            new Message() {Text = "An investment in knowledge pays the best 
                interest."},
            new Message() {Text = "Early to bed and early to rise makes a 
                man healthy, wealthy, and wise."},
            new Message()
            {
                Text = "It's fine to celebrate success but it is more 
                     important to heed the lessons of failure."
            },
        };

        Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>(msgs);
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And Below is the xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="PrismAppTutorial.Views.QuoteDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">

        <ListView x:Name="lvAuthorQuotes"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Padding="20,10" 
                                         Orientation="Vertical" 
                                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use an observable collection in the first place? If the observable collection is the right thing, `Messages` should have no setter, instead change the existing collection...

Comment: Just `Clear` the observable collection, then add the items to it. That should work.

Comment: @Haukinger, why shouldn't I use the observable collection? Remember that down the line I may need to update these items in the list. Plus, I don't see why a Setter is an issue here. But please, by all means, if you have a better solution, bring it on.

Comment: Normally, if you use an observable collection, you _change_ it, you don't _replace_ it. That is, even though there's no setter, you cann still add or remove items through the getter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had set the `Messages` as private and not public. This needs to be public so as to be applied in the view.